# How can I remove div with PHP?

Tags: php

I want to remove `<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2"></div>` contents **IF** `$chkupdates->count` is equal 0

How can I remove it based on this following code?

This is my code:

```
<?php 
    $chkupdates = checkUpdatesCount();
    if($chkupdates->showUpdates){ 
        if($isSuperAdmin){ ?>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
            <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/updates/" method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-update btn-block">
                <div class="h5"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg"></i> <span>Updates</span><span class="pull-right label_update blink_me_update" id="updatescount"><?php if($chkupdates->count > 0){ echo $chkupdates->count; }; ?></span></div>
              </button>
            </form>
        </div>
<?php
        } 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: use jquery make an id of the div and use $("#divid").hide(); inside the condition

Comment: why not just enclose the whole div inside `if($chkupdates->count <= 0)`

Comment: I just want to use it with PHP not jquery . You mean it's not possible to remove it by PHP ?

Comment: You could even simplify the two `if` blocks you already have to `if ($chkupdates->showUpdates && $isSuperAdmin && $chkupdates->count != 0)`

Comment: Oh yes you are right. it was so simple. cause I've added  $chkupdates->count != 0 inside div that's why it doesn't work. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, simplify your logic and include the extra condition (hide if 0 / show if not 0), eg

```php
<?php
$chkupdates = checkUpdatesCount();
if ($chkupdates->showUpdates && $isSuperAdmin && $chkupdates->count != 0) : ?>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
  <!-- etc -->
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php for an explanation on the alternate syntax for control structures.